# How do I convert the string formatted array to an actual array in the Controller?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am submitting a form to the controller, the form consists of properties which one of them is an array.

```js
$("#parsedQuestions input").val(JSON.stringify(questionsArr));
var formData = JSON.stringify($("#trainingForm").serialize());

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("SaveTraining", "Training")',
    data:  formData,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
        console.log(errorMessage);
    },
    success: function(data) {console.log(data)} 
});
```

The `questionsArr` is an array, but it is being returned as a plain string like this:

```
"[[\"1\",\"11\",\"111\",\"1111\",\"1111\",\"11111\"],[\"1\",\"22\",\"222\",\"2222\",\"22222\",\"2222222\"]]"
```

My Controller

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveTraining([FromForm] KII_TrainingModel formData)
{
}
```

It's a 2-dimensional array supposedly.

In my model, I tried to make this property `ParsedQuestions` as `string[][]` and `List`.
But I only get one element, which is the formatted string array.

I have looked everywhere to find a solution but can't find one.
Any answers or ideas will be appreciated.

If I don't stringify it, it looks like this:

[image]

If I do, then it returns this:

```
"[[\"1\",\"11\",\"111\",\"1111\",\"1111\",\"11111\"],[\"1\",\"22\",\"222\",\"2222\",\"22222\",\"2222222\"]]"
```

Any suggestions even as to how to convert this string to an actual array?

Comment: It's JSON, because you specifically used `JSON.stringify` to convert it to JSON.  Thus, you need to use a JSON module to decode it back to its component parts.

Comment: Even without the JSON.stringify it's being submitted as a string

Comment: it's being submitted as a string

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the way that sets the array into the text field and retrieves it from the form, the array will be in string value.

Instead, you have to append the array into `formData` via [`FormData.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) similar to below:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < questionsArr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < questionsArr[i].length; j++) {
        formData.append(`ParsedQuestions[${i}][${j}]`, questionsArr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

And this line is no longer needed:

```js
$("#parsedQuestions input").val(JSON.stringify(questionsArr));
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote this as a sample:  you can access the data indexing into both arrays.

```html
    let ar = [["1", "11", "111", "1111", "1111", "11111"], ["1", "22", "222", "2222", "22222", "2222222"]]
let ans =    ar[0][2];
console.log(ans);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).